# For focus and directrix of parabola, is $p$ a number or a distance?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found this solution for a question of finding a differential equation for which the family of solutions is a set of parabolas whose axes of symmetry are parallel to the $x$-axis and in which the distance between the focus and vertex is $a/2$. I believe the solution to be wrong, as I wrote in the comment below. Just wondering if I am correct or not?
[image]

Comment: What is $p$? ${}$

Comment: This shows what *p* is: https://ibb.co/BcVHVzX